# What is the point of a horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

During his years in hiding, when no one came to help Voldemort, none of his Horcruxes actively helped him. The fact is, the Slytherin Locket, the Hufflepuff Cup, and the Ravenclaw Diadem were hidden and would have stayed that way if no one had collected them.

The worst part is if Voldemort dies first, then most of the Horcruxes would have stayed hidden, given how well-protected they were. Hence Voldemort would remain dead. Am I missing something, or is there something very dumb about this?

Horcruxes only make sense if they can somehow intuit the master piece of soul has been destroyed or is in serious trouble. In that event, they should automatically activate. If not, this seems to be an unnecessary waste of time.

I am guessing, if Voldemort himself is the first to die, some knowledgeable wizard would have to perform the whole boiling-liquid-blood-of-enemy-servant procedure, like at the end of *Goblet of Fire*, and instead of a weakened Voldemort, throw in maybe the Hufflepuff Cup or the Ravenclaw Diadem.

Comment: Here is the "point" of a Horcrux: "You split your soul and hide part of it in an object outside the body. Then, even if one’s body is attacked or destroyed, one cannot die, for part of the soul remains earthbound and undamaged." As long as there are Horcruxes, Voldemort *cannot die first*. As well, Voldemort's Horcruxes kept him from dying when his Avada Kedavra curse rebounded and hit him, when Voldemort tried to kill Harry when Harry was a baby. The Horcruxes served their purpose exactly as they were supposed to.

Comment: I can't see why this question is downvoted, closed. It is a perfectly valid question...

Comment: This isn't a good question, but it's on topic and "too localized" is no longer a valid close reason.

Answer (score 4):

Voldemort's greatest wish was to live forever, so he created the horcruxes. With any one of them in tact, part of him still lived. Without a horcrux, he could not. That was the whole point of creating them.

You are correct in that a horcrux being forgotten and "lost" does nothing *actively* positive towards Voldemort's goal, but a forgotten/lost part of Voldemort living somewhere is better than the alternative.

Comment: wait a sec - Voldemort doesn't need a Horcrux to be "resurreted". As long as one exists (now matter if lost or not) he can't die, i.e., his soul can't pass from the world of the living to the dead.

Comment: fair enough. restored is probably a better word choice. agree?

Comment: I think not being able to die (in the sense of the soul moving to the world of the dead or whatever) is the most accurate term. Voldemort didn't need a Horcrux to "restore" himself from the "less than a ghost" thing to a being with a more or less human body.

Comment: @mort there is a _world_ of dead?

Comment: The "afterlife", "heaven", "hell" or wherever a soul goes to after death.